# searched a lot but keyPress() not working

Tags: java, keypress

I searched and googled but cant find answer to this:

`keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_1);` should hold key `1`.But this function is implementing as if key 1is presses once.Please give a real solution.Though I saw a similiar question there was no answer

Comment: Can you post any more of your sample code?  I'll also take a look and try to create a fiddle to help.

Comment: Also are you trying to generate a key being pressed, or detect when a key is pressed?

Comment: Did you try to specify a keyRelease event with a delay in between? E.g. `robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_1);robot.delay(100);robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_1);`

Comment: robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT);
this line should hold key right but on my notepad i could see that it is behaving like i pressed it just once

Comment: @john thankyou but i have. a doubt that if keyPress function holds a key then how the program executes the next line

Comment: @Mark thankyou for your response i just wanted to know why keyPress function is not holding the key

Comment: Depending on the os, KeyPress will trigger and after a short dely, be called repeatedly  until released